# section __text/__text address out of range file for architecture x86_64 while integrating web3swift MercuryProtocol

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, arm7, web3swift

I've been stuck here for 2 days tried all methods but still failed to build successfully not able to fix section __text/__text address out of range file for architecture x86_64 while integrating web3swift MercuryProtocol.